# JavaScript variables - new var altering original value

Tags: javascript

It's been a while since I've touched JavaScript, but something has got me flummoxed, simple I just know I should know it, but it's causing me a massive headache for the past hour!

Scenario;

```
Mop = {
  els : [],
  pool : [],
  generate : function(){
    for (var i=0; i<Mop.els.length; i++){
      Mop.pool.push(i)
    }
  },
  oneAtime : {
    p : Mop.pool,
    runit : function(){
      timerID = window.setTimeout(function(){
        Mop.show()
      });
    }
  },
  show : function(){
     var p = Mop.oneAtime.p;
     var r = Math.floor(p.length * Math.random());
     p.splice(r,1);
  },
  init : function(){
    Mop.els = $(".cells");
    Mop.generate();
    Mop.oneAtime();
  }
}
Mop.init()
```

A long winded way to say it's a problem with variable assigning. But I thought I'd show the context.

In short, invoking `Mop.show()` affects both the arrays `Mop.pool`, and `Mop.oneAtime.p`, even though the latter was assigned `Mop.pool` value, and `Mop.pool` is not touched again. `Mop.pool` must remain un-altered.

I can hear someone laughing at how easy this must be - but I just cannot work out why both arrays are affected by the splice() method! Scope, closure, something like that I bet, I've tried all I can think of...

Comment: JavaScript doesn't create a copy of the array when you assign it to a variable. `p` and `Mop.oneAtime.p` refer to the same array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Also I assume that your actual code is slightly different because in your example, `p : Mop.pool,` will throw a runtime error (`Moo` doesn't have a value at that moment).

Comment: I extracted meaningful bits of a much longer bit of code. I think the key question is how do I assign a variable (array) to another variable and alter it, with the original being affected? I've googled away but don't know really how to phrase it I guess!

Comment: I think you mean "without". And you do this by *cloning* or *copying* the array. Just as shown in the linked question.